# Cloud Firestore queries and documentSnapshots

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to perform a query to get specific documents in a sub-collection. The function runs and doesn't give an error but the array in both the response and the console log is always empty. What could be the mistake? The code I am using is the following:

```
   export const delay_query = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     const current_timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds
     admin.firestore().collection(`Message/{UserId}/{ChatRoomId}`).where('creationTime', '<', current_timestamp).get()
     .then((snapshot) => {


       console.log(snapshot.docs)
       response.send(snapshot.docs)
     })
     .catch( error => {
       console.log(error)
       response.status(500).send(error)
     })
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to query a collection called "Message/{UserId}/{ChatRoomId}".  It is exactly that string.  If you are expecting that those values in curly braces are being substituted with other values, that is not happening.  You are effectively querying a subcollection that doesn't exist.

If you want to substitute values into that query, you will first have to figure out where those values come from, as it's not obvious from your code.  If you are trying to use JavaScript string interpolation here, you will need to use a dollar sign to insert the value of a variable, like "Message/${UserId}/${ChatRoomId}".  Of course, you have to define UserId and ChatRoomId first.

Comment: I am technically trying to query every document in every subcollection ChatroomID. Is that even possible? Like I need to query every chatRoomId

Comment: You can certainly query all documents in a collection.  You are just doing it wrong as I described in my answer.

Comment: would I fix it by just querying "Message"? Or would I have to use a for... like (for const user in UserIds) and then use ${user}